# I can't change the font size

Tags: fontsize

I can't do something so simple like changing the font size . No matter what number I write in `\documentclass[10pt]{article}`, I'm not able neither to reduce nor to increase the size.

Although after `\documentclass` you can see `[10pt]`, reality is that the actual font size the text is compiled is 11 (I think).

I wonder if the problem has its root in any of this packages:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,fontenc,titlesec}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{url}
\pagestyle{fancy} % seleccionamos un estilo
\lhead{TEBF} % texto izquierda de la cabecera
\chead{Práctica 10}
\rhead{Jorge Becerra} % número de página a la derecha
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} % grosor de la línea de la cabecera
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. The valid values are `10pt` (default), `11pt` and `12pt`, is there no change with the two latter?

Comment: How do you know the size?  I'd expect `10pt` here.  For larger text, I'd use `{\large my words}` and so forth. See [this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Sizing_text) for more information.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Please post **complete** code i.e. a complete small document which demonstrates the issue. This is a lot more useful than mere fragments.

Comment: 12pt is the only one that I achieve a different size. But no difference between 10 and 11

Comment: It seems unlikely that the `10pt` and `11pt` options of the standard `article` class use the same size fonts. If you think you have that problem please post an 11pt document that shows the problem, otherwise there is nothing really anyone can do to help.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I've just solved it. It was just a couple of "{" missing. Thank you for your time and attencion.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem with the input, acknowledged by the poster.